# rewriterule openlitespeed no me funciona

Tags: rewriterule, openlitespeed

Tengo un problema con la regla de reescritura en mi servidor openlitespeed. Dentro de la página de inicio de mi página (wordpress): `dominioweb.com` tengo un botón que al hacer clic me lleva a un test que está en otra aplicación web con el siguiente dominio: `dominioapp.com/test/cualquier_cosa`. Quiero que al hacer clic en dicho boton de "test" me lleve a la aplicacion pero que me siga manteniendo `dominioweb.com/test/any_thing`

Este es mi htaccess:

```html
#HTACCESS FINAL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ https://dominioapp.com/test/$1/ [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

El problema es que no hace nada y me lleva a un 404 cuando pongo la url/test/

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: esta regla:
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ https://dominioapp.com/test/$1/ [L]

No me la está aplicando.

Estoy en mi página dominioweb.com. Pincho en un botón con un enlace a https://dominioweb.com/test/curso y lo que pretendo con el rewriterule es que me muestre el contenido que hay en https://dominioapp.com/test/curso pero manteniéndome en la url: https://dominioweb.com/test/curso